# How to change the text color of a QxtLabel

Tags: qt, libqxt

I'm checking out [libqxt](http://www.libqxt.org/) (an extension library for Qt) and cannot change the text color of a QxTLabel; it's driving me nuts.

QxTLabel extends QFrame.  QFrame doesn't know anything about text.  I tried changing the palette via the Form Editor but that didn't appear to do anything either.

I also tried to change the style sheet but, again, QFrame doesn't know about text and QxTLabel isn't giving anything up either.

Nothing is jumping out at me from the [full member list](http://doc.libqxt.org/0.6.0/qxtlabel-members.html) for QxTLabel either. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was harder to find than I expected but I eventually got it:

```
ui.myQxTLabel->setStyleSheet( "QFrame { color: white }" );
```

Previously, I was trying to set *foreground-color*.